# Call a method in an expression tree lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I am trying to emulate this lambda call with expression trees:

```
myList.AsQueryable().GroupBy(g=>g.Name).Select(s => s.FirstOrDefault());
```

So far i got myself here:

```
public Expression Distinct (IQueryable queryable, string propertyName)
{
    var propInfo = queryable.ElementType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var collectionType = queryable.ElementType;

    var groupParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(collectionType, "g");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupParameterExpression, propInfo);
    var groupLambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, groupParameterExpression);
    var groupExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "GroupBy", new Type[] { collectionType, propInfo.PropertyType }, queryable.Expression, groupLambda);

    var selectParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(groupExpression.Type, "s");
    var selectFirstOrDefaultMethodExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", new Type[] { collectionType }, selectParameterExpression);
    var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda(selectFirstOrDefaultMethodExpression, selectParameterExpression);
    return Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", new Type[] { groupExpression.Type, selectParameterExpression.Type }, groupExpression, selectLambda);
}
```

This part passess okay:

```
var groupParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(collectionType, "g");
var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupParameterExpression, propInfo);
var groupLambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, groupParameterExpression);
var groupExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "GroupBy", new Type[] { collectionType, propInfo.PropertyType }, queryable.Expression, groupLambda);
```

I get a valid expression in `groupExpression` and the `type` received in this case when calling a `Name` property from a model is:

`IGrouping<string, Product>` where a Product is a model that looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`selectParameterExpression` is a parameter expression with a type of `IGrouping<string,Product>` .

I get an exception when i try to call `FirstOrDefault` here:

```
var selectFirstOrDefaultMethodExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", new Type[] { collectionType }, selectParameterExpression);
```

> No generic method 'FirstOrDefault' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Comment: what is stored in the collectionType variable?

Comment: Did you check the arguments to that call? Are they what you expect? (Answer must be no.)

Comment: @WicherVisser `var collectionType = queryable.ElementType;` it's the generic type with which the queryable is called

Comment: I am aware of that. But what value is it being set to upon runtime when you get the exception?

Comment: Please check the runtime values. Anyone can read the code. It's unclear what ends up in those variables at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with that code.

First, when using `Expression.Call` to call `Queryable` methods, you have to wrap the lambdas with [`Expression.Quote`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.quote(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to let them be treated as `Expression<Func<...>>` rather than just `Func<...>`.

Second, the `Select` parameter type in your example should be `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` while you are passing `groupExpression.Type` which is `IQueryable<IGrouping<TElement, TKey>>`, i.e. you need to extract the `IGrouping` part, for instance like this:

```
groupExpression.Type.GetGenericArguments().Single()
```

Finally, the `Select` call generic arguments should be `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`, `TElement`, which can be obtained for instance from `selectParameterExpression.Type`, `selectLambda.Body.Type`.

So the working method could be like this:

```
public Expression Distinct(IQueryable queryable, string propertyName)
{
    var propInfo = queryable.ElementType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var collectionType = queryable.ElementType;

    var groupParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(collectionType, "g");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupParameterExpression, propInfo);
    var groupLambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, groupParameterExpression);
    var groupExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "GroupBy", new Type[] { collectionType, propInfo.PropertyType }, queryable.Expression, Expression.Quote(groupLambda));

    var selectParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(groupExpression.Type.GetGenericArguments().Single(), "s");
    var selectFirstOrDefaultMethodExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "FirstOrDefault", new Type[] { collectionType }, selectParameterExpression);
    var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda(selectFirstOrDefaultMethodExpression, selectParameterExpression);
    return Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", new Type[] { selectParameterExpression.Type, selectLambda.Body.Type }, groupExpression, Expression.Quote(selectLambda));
}
```